# Can't Compile Because I haven't loaded Babel - But I'm not using Babel?

Tags: errors, babel

I tried compiling a document with an included Hebrew word. I copy and pasted the `\usepackag`e example loading English and French as an example. Since then, my document will not compile no matter what I do. I have completely removed babel from the preamble and it now complains that I am not loading English. I tried using `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, but then it tells me I'm not loading french. I add french, it complains about my encoding. But I don't have a single french word or accent in my text!

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
```

This will not compile, with the following logfile:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for     SUSE Linux) (format=pdflatex 2013.12.10)  20 MAR 2014 19:43
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/home/michael/Dropbox/ProjectMalynne/TEX/.Main.tex.swp
(/home/michael/Dropbox/ProjectMalynne/TEX/.Main.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/cjhebrew/cjhebrew.sty
Package: cjhebrew 2004/08/27 v. 0.1a cjhebrew Hebrew Typesetting System
) (/tmp/.Main.tex.aux

/tmp/.Main.tex.aux:6: Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the language     english yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \select@language{english}

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 244 strings out of 493315
 2957 string characters out of 6145892
 52158 words of memory out of 5000000
 3777 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,17p,200b,49s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

/tmp/.Main.tex.aux:6:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Again, I'm not loading babel, and I keep getting exceptions. I tried trashing the `aux` files, but it's no use. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you tried deleting the auxiliary files and compiling again?

Comment: @Jubobs 'I tried trashing the aux files...' so I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Have you tried copying the file to somewhere outside Dropbox and compiling?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just remembered that there had been questions about difficulties compiling stuff on Dropbox. I'm not familiar with `.swp` files in the context of TeX especially except editor-dependent uses. Should I?

Comment: @cfr `.swp` files in the context of latex are (usually) about Scientific Workplace (from McKichan).  i've had enormous trouble getting paper submissions into “real” tex from one of those things.

Comment: You could include `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}` to see what packages are loaded (so far). Maybe it helps to find the cause for your problem.

Comment: Thanks all. The issue got fixed after a reboot. Thanks for pointing to the duplicate; I'm thinking it might have to do with dropbox that I still couldn't compile after deleting the *.aux file.